# World Map - Geo-location pinpoint

Tags: php, geolocation

If I have a map of the world in JPG format, and I want to dynamically plot a point on the map based on an IP addresses geo-location...what's the best way to go about doing this in PHP?

Or is there a better suggestion?

#### Edit

I know that I can use Google Maps to do this, but I want to know if I can do the same with just a regular world map JPG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need an IP -> coordinate look up web service.

Then once you have the coordinates, you will need to transform them into your bitmap's coordinates. So you will need to know your bitmap's map projection. it is probably a cylindrical projection - perhaps Mercator?  The cylindrical projections are generally quite simple and you could roll your own math to do the transform. It would be easier and more light weight that bringing in an external library (eg. Proj.4 for C++ or Proj4JS for JavaScript)

Comment: Also phpmapscript wraps proj4, but then you have to install mapserver.

Comment: Yes there's always the MapServer solution but I think that is probably overkill for the OP. Sev could get the coordinate and then simply plot it into a Google Maps control - this saves faffing with projections, and the user would have an interactive map. of course Sev may have a particular bitmap that must be used...

Answer (score 0):

See [Google Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/index.html) and [IP to Country](http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/).